# Storing big array (1 GB) in memcache

Tags: php, memcached

I am beginner with memcached and my question is simple. Is there any option how to store 1 GB array into memcached?

Thanks for answers.

Comment: That's an incredibly big array. Are you sure it's 1Gb?

Comment: The default maximum object size in memcached is 1MB.

Comment: It's because i'm implementing vector model for information-retrieval. And i have file with indexes which is 90 MB big and is encoded in json. And when i load this and decode it, my script shows me that size is about 1 GB...

Comment: Hmm, Redis max is 512MB.. closer but not close enough

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not recommended to store in Cache

- Break the array into pieces
- Use a file storage, maybe write a json file or something to access
- Use a database connection to store the data (recommended)

1GB of array is not recommended to store into Caching system. Only store those information which are used too frequent into your frontend and not like an entire database.